# Missing patches installation in sharepoint 2010 farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

14.0.7180.5001 and 14.0.7159.5000 this patches are missing in SharePoint 2010.

I have a doubt here do i need to install both patches14.0.7180.5001 and 14.0.7159.5000 or 14.0.7180.5001 this only patch also contains all the previous updates (14.0.7159.5000) too?

Could you please guide me how to proceed in this scenario?

Thanks,
Santhosh

Answer (score 0):

Each security update includes all fixes that have been released for both security and non-security related issues up to that point for the patched component.

Just install the Uber packages of the latest CU and you are good.

Reference:

https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2020/02/11/sharepoint-patching-best-practices/